Is [ʍ] a fricative or approximant?
Is [ʍ] a fricative or approximant? I need a definitive answer to this. Some say it's a fricative, some say it's an approximant, some say it's both, but what's the truth?

See https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/33722

Per the official IPA chart, it's a fricative.
But you'll find these nice discrete categories on the chart aren't always so clearly delineated in practice. The distinction between a fricative and an approximant, for example, isn't always clear; if you look at the official chart, you'll find ʕ is officially defined as a fricative, but in practice it's generally used for an approximant. There's no language in the world that distinguishes between a pharyngeal fricative and a pharyngeal approximant, so this doesn't cause any problems.
